# what is the difference between Object and Object ACL in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I added a file into AWS S3 bucket. The access of the bucket is set to public. In the permissions, I set `object` and `object ACL` to `read` for everyone.

[image]

But I am not clear about the difference between `Object` and `Object ACL`, could you please explain their differences?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific setting that you are wanting to configure for your bucket? Sometimes using a **Bucket Policy** is more suitable than using Object Access Control Lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Object** refers to permissions to access the object (file) itself, such as downloading the object.

**Object ACL** refers to permissions to access/change the Access Control List of the object. That is, the permissions associated with the object.